# I have multiple Stack Overflow IDs associated with my Stack Exchange Open ID. How do I clean it up?

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I have an existing Stack Overflow account but somehow made another Stack Overflow account while using the StackExchange app, so now I have unpredictable behavior when I visit Stack Overflow.  Sometimes I'm using one account, sometimes I'm using another.

You can see the different reputation that I have because the Open ID links to a different account than when I actually visit Stack Overflow.  I'm not concerned with the reputation, but this makes it hard for me to manage my questions and answers because I cannot easily control which account I am using when posting.

Is there a way to delete one of my accounts?  I can provide the exact ID but not sure if posting it is safe.

[image]

Comment: I think the team can merge the accounts.

Comment: Ah, found the option in support.  I'll update when the issue is resolved.

Comment: Merging is the solution.  It cleaned up my Open ID so it behaves properly now.  Thanks.